# How to write a comma to a file in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following code is typing the two quotes (around comma )as well.

```
fp = OpenAppend["Math.txt"];
mycomma = “,”;
(*var1 and var2 are variables*)
Write[fp,var1 ,mycomma,var2];
(*other attempts Write[fp,var1 ,"\,",var2]; *)
(*other attempts Write[fp,var1 , \, ,var2]; *)
Close[fp];
```

Comment: This might help you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73968/comma-issue-from-number-point-in-csv-export

Comment: use `WriteString[fp,var1,",",var2,"\n" ]` . Note you need to add the terminating line end if needed.

Comment: alternately, `Write[fp,var1,OutputForm[","],var2]`, or you can specify `FormatType -> OutputForm` as an option to `OpenWrite`.